# Sass mixin to target odd children elements

Tags: css, sass, styles, mixins, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create a left/right image and text layout, where for example:
1st element has the image on the left, text on the right,
2nd element has the image on the right, text on the left,
3rd element - as 1st
4th element - as 2nd

etc.
The gotcha is that depending on the layout, left/right padding of the text container should also alternate between 0 and 5 em.

One simple way to do this would be to define padding for the element and then override it with a selector such as :nth-child(odd).

**However, I would like to make it more elegant with a mixin/ @if rule.**

Now, this is what I've got so far (applying it to the text container div):

```
@mixin alternating-padding() {
@if (&: nth-child(odd)) {
    padding: 5em 0 5em 5em;
} @else {
        padding: 5em 5em 5em 0;   } }
```

Applied:

```
&__text {
    @extend .col-6;
    @include alternating-padding;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

Which is not working.
Any ideas of how I can improve this? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A scss `@if` rule is evaluated when the scss gets compiled. At that point theres no DOM to check against. So there is no way you can decide if its a even or odd child by the time you compile the scss (and where the `@if` rule is evaluated).

Using `:nth-child(odd)` in css is the proper way to go.

If you still want to use a mixin, it could look like this:

```
@mixin alternating-padding() {
  padding: 5em 5em 5em 0;

  &:nth-child(odd) {
    padding: 5em 0 5em 5em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian, this is seriously a great explanation. I've not thought about the order in which files are compiled being a factor here!

Comment: It's not really about the compile order. It's because the whole compiling happens when you're coding. Your server serves pure css to the clients at runtime. At this point the process of compiling (and therefore the evaluation of _any_ programmatic scss feature - like an `@if` clause) is finished long ago.